# como puedo mostrarlo los datos en el navegador

Tags: javascript

Tenemos una serie de coches con sus características: nombre, marca, modelo, año.

```
('seat600', 'Seat','600',1970)
('r4L','Renault', '4L',1975)
('Ibiza','Seat','Ibiza',1990)
('c2CV','Citroën', '2CV',1980)
('toledo','Seat','Toledo',1999)
```

1. Crear una clase/constructor Coche con todos sus campos como propiedades

```javascript
class Cotxe {
    constructor(nom, marca, model, any){
    this.nom=nom;
    this.marca=marca;
    this.model=model;
    this.any=any;
    }
    mostrarCotxe() {
        console.log (this.nom+this.marca+this.model+this.any);
        document.write (this.nom+this.marca+this.model+this.any+ "<br>");
    }
}
var obj1=new Cotxe('seat600', 'Seat','600',1970);
var obj2=new Cotxe('r4L','Renault', '4L',1975);
var obj3=new Cotxe('Ibiza','Seat','Ibiza',1990);
var obj4=new Cotxe('c2CV','Citroën', '2CV',1980);
var obj5=new Cotxe('toledo','Seat','Toledo',1999);

const Cotxes = [];
Cotxes.push (obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5);
console.log(Cotxes);
```

Comment: Cambia el título de la pregunta, te sugiero poner algo así como "¿Cómo se crea una función constructora con métodos en javascript y mostrar su salida?", tambien leete [ask], aprende lo que es un [constructor](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp) (yo lo acabo de hacer ahora mismo) y mirate las correcciones que he hecho a tu código aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/4kLna0md/

Comment: @masterguru, creo que deberías te añadir el código de ejemplo como respuesta. SO permite añadir código y además ejecutarlo en la propia plataforma.

Comment: @MitaCloud: En este caso prefiero no hacerlo, porque no es una respuesta exacta a lo que pide, solo una aproximación y para que vaya entendiendo javascript y las herramientas de las que dispone online para jugar con el.  Ademas esta haciendo un ejercicio de 9 partes relacionadas y esta solo es la primera y no estoy seguro si le interesa o no el tema, o tan solo quiere sacarselo de encima (aunque a mi me va bien para practicar pues mi nivel de javascript es muy bajo, aunque no quiero hacerle todos los deberes tampoco)

Comment: @masterguru Obviamente hacerle los deberes no, pero yo personalmente daría tu respuesta como valida(aun que en vez de hacer el `console.log` de cada objeto, haría un `for`).  Por otra parte, creo que la pregunta del OP es bastante clara(aun que mejorable) y tu respuesta(enlace) le da una posible solución a su problema. También comentar que, si el OP tiene otros problemas, siempre es bienvenido a abrir una nueva pregunta o ampliación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar los datos en el navegador debes pasarle algun valor al metodo `mostrarCotxe`, que no usas en tu código y que contiene la función `document.write` que es la que realmente escribe en el navegador.

Aún así, como tu código no estaba bien y no funcionaba he creado una aproximación a lo que me parece que quieres:

```js
function Cotxe(nom, marca, model, any) {
  this.nom = nom;
  this.marca = marca;
  this.model = model;
  this.any = any;
  this.mostrarCotxe = function () {
    // console.log(this.nom + this.marca + this.model + this.any);
    document.write(this.nom + this.marca + this.model + this.any + "<br>");
  };
}

var obj1 = new Cotxe('seat600', 'Seat', '600', 1970);
var obj2 = new Cotxe('r4L', 'Renault', '4L', 1975);
var obj3 = new Cotxe('Ibiza', 'Seat', 'Ibiza', 1990);
var obj4 = new Cotxe('c2CV', 'Citroën', '2CV', 1980);
var obj5 = new Cotxe('toledo', 'Seat', 'Toledo', 1999);

const Cotxes = [];
Cotxes.push(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5);
// console.log(Cotxes);

obj1.mostrarCotxe();
obj2.mostrarCotxe();
obj3.mostrarCotxe();
obj4.mostrarCotxe();
obj5.mostrarCotxe();
```